# How do I configure a Server-Side Console Project in EWL?

Tags: console-application, worker, enterprise-web-library

I know I have to define this section in Development.xml:

```
<serverSideConsoleProjects>
    <project>
        <Name>Program</Name>
        <AssemblyName>Assembly</AssemblyName>
    </project>
</serverSideConsoleProjects>
```

Do I have to do anything else? What effect does this actually have on the solution or on any of the Package Manager Console operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, declaring a server-side console project causes that project's build output to be included in the `Logic Packages` folder that gets created in your solution folder by the `ExportLogic` console operation. To my knowledge there is nothing else that EWL does right now with these projects.

Comment: I think it also makes it so that when you debug the project in Visual Studio, it can actually find the configuration properly.

Comment: As long as you call `AppTools.Init`, EWL should be able to find the configuration. I don't think the `Development.xml` entry has anything to do with that.